# Hash having slashes added when appending to a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, hashlib

When using os.urandom(64) it generates a string with 64 random characters, this works as intended but oddly when turning it, alongside other data into a list (I need to do this to writerow into a csv file) it turns the slashes into double slashes.

**Normal Salt:**
b'\xfe\x82;o\xa6\x8e\xfeF]\x140\x02+\xe9\x82\xa0j\x0e\xe19n\x02\xa0_t\xb6\xa8\xe1u\xc6\x94\x9a\xb94P\t\x83\xe0\x0e&B\xda\xe5)62\xa3l\x807\xb6\xd8\x0bU\xd0\xf1\xe0\xf7R:\xbc\xfe\x86\x96'

**Salt within the list:**
"b'\xfe\x82;o\xa6\x8e\xfeF]\x140\x02+\xe9\x82\xa0j\x0e\xe19n\x02\xa0_t\xb6\xa8\xe1u\xc6\x94\x9a\xb94P\t\x83\xe0\x0e&B\xda\xe5)62\xa3l\x807\xb6\xd8\x0bU\xd0\xf1\xe0\xf7R:\xbc\xfe\x86\x96'"

Code:

```
def SaltGenerator():  # Used to generate Salts to be stored, will not be run in final code as salts will be stored
    salt = os.urandom(64)  # Generates a cryptographically secure random string
    return salt

def CSVAppend(Directory,Value):
    with open (os.path.join(sys.path[0],Directory),"a", newline = "") as Write:
        writer = csv.writer(Write)
        writer.writerow(Value)
import os
import csv
import sys

Salt = str(SaltGenerator())
print(Salt)
UsernameSaltHashedPasswordAppend=[Salt]
print(UsernameSaltHashedPasswordAppend)
CSVAppend("UsernameSaltHashedPassword",UsernameSaltHashedPasswordAppend)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.writer` takes Unicode strings.  `os.urandom()` returns a byte string.  You've converted it to a Unicode string by calling `str()`, but you get a byte string representation (`b"..."`) which has escape codes for unprintable bytes and double backslash escapes for backslashes.  Instead, use `.hex()` to convert to a readable hexadecimal Unicode string.

You can use `bytes.fromhex()` to convert back once you read the string from the CSV:

```py
import csv
import os

salt = os.urandom(64)

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow([salt.hex()])

with open('test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        salt2 = bytes.fromhex(line[0])
        print(salt == salt2)  # True
```

test.csv (example):

```
151c5611a5107654c9326ef7a99f5fb6aebabc579bb8f1785aa59f485008987e370eb4c8b4d856995164974539147a24e989711634865b8fc8d39bc238adfc8e
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing a list, the function used on each item on the list underneath is the function **repr**() which escapes backslash with double backslash.
However, when printing a string with `print(str)`, it is the function **str**() of the object that is called.

You could try the following to understand:

- `print("this is a tab \t and this is a linebreak \n END")`
- `print(["this is a tab \t and this is a linebreak \n END"])`

As you can see, the first one formats the string (Using the str.**str**() function) while the second one does not (Using the str.**repr**() function).

Does this make sense?

However, it should not change the behaviour, just the display. The string `Salt` is always the same, it is just not displayed the same way whether it is inside a list or not.

Comment: This was not the issue I was having, as when I took the contents of the Salt from the csv file in another python program the resulting hash was different, the other users solution worked however